# Is this an appropriate forum to ask questions about personal health?

Tags: discussion

E.g. body cleanliness, birthing/pre-natal, sex, child health, etc.

Comment: FYI there is a [health SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health?referrer=3bnJk5Umd0S9V8Fef65Ucg2) that is in commitment phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quoting our FAQ:](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq)

> Fitness - Stack Exchange is for fitness professionals, athletes,
>   trainers and enthusiasts. If you have a question about …
>
> - improving your exercise performance or technique
> - choosing a training program
> - nutrition as it relates to exercise
> - gear and gadgets used during exercise
> - achieving physique milestones
> - injury prevention
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - the rules of a sport
> - a purchase recommendation
> - nutrition unrelated to exercise, such as food safety, nutritional needs for children, etc.
> - trainer certification -- it’s for professionals, but not about the profession
> - wellness, general health, medical advice and injuries unrelated to exercise
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Then the topics you mentioned are definitely not on-topic.

Comment: Thanks - there really ought to be a "stack" dedicated to general health

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer I suggest looking at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for proposals related to health, nutrition, and topics that we don't cover. I do not know which of those are still around, but you can check for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I knew of that site but couldn't remember the name.